# Find if a Google Document is blank using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-realtime-api

How to find if a google document is blank using App script? I tried this

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < para.length; i++) 
  {
    if (para[i].getText() != "")
     count++;  
  }
  if(count=0)
   Logger.log("Empty");
  else
   Logger.log("NOT EMPTY")
}
```

I am sure that this works good only if the document has text content alone. I am eager to know if there is any way to find if the document is blank.

Answer (score 2):

A document always has at least one paragraph element, so you can't really rely on a zero-count return. You could check the length of the elements in the body and then trigger some more tests for a true check for blankness.

```
function blankDoc() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // Find the number of children in the body
  Logger.log(body.getNumChildren());

  for(var i = 0; i<body.getNumChildren();i++) {
    Logger.log(body.getChild(i).getType());

    // Test for text in the paragraph
    if(body.getChild(i).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {

      // get the text, check for a 0 length
      var para = body.getChild(i).asParagraph().getText();
      Logger.log(para.length);
      // use another if block to do something...
    }
  }
  // check for images
  var imgs = body.getImages();

  if(imgs.length > 0) {
    Logger.log("There's an image");
  }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it gets you closer. Go through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) on what elements to check for in the `Body` of the doc and just add from there.

Comment: thanks for the idea, tried this `function blankDoc() 
{
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var blankDoc;
  var child = body.getNumChildren();
  var para = body.getChild(0).asParagraph().getText();
  if(child==1 && para.length == 0) 
  {
    blankDoc = true;
  }
  else
  {
    blankDoc = false;
  }
  return blankDoc;
}` and it worked @brian

Comment: Awesome. If you want to close this, you can click the green checkmark on the left.