# How to find whether the google document is empty using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to find whether the document is empty.

I have tried with

```
if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText().length < 1); {
    showAlert('Document is empty')
    return;
}
```

but this bypasses the image or any other special items in the document.

How do I determine the document is null or totally empty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find if a Google Document is blank using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999152/find-if-a-google-document-is-blank-using-google-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please think of this as one of several answers. How about comparing the filesize of both Document and a new Document? It has found that when from the Document which includes some images, texts and comments, all images, texts and comments are removed, the size becomes that of new Document. I thought that by using this, it can know whether the Document is empty.

### Sample script :

```
var id = "### Document ID ###"; // Please input ID here.

var tempId = DocumentApp.create("temp").getId();
var newdocument = DriveApp.getFileById(tempId).getBlob().getBytes().length;
var document = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes().length;
if (newdocument == document) {
  Logger.log("Empty")
}
DriveApp.removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(tempId));
```

### Note :

- Because I worry about the filesize might be different for each environment, at the sample script, I retrieved the size using `temp` Document. This `temp` Document is removed at the last of script.

I don't know whether this method is useful for you. If this was not useful, I'm sorry.